# Saving data and query it in different threads with Realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm experiencing threading issues with `Realm` (I'm using version 3.7).

If I save some data in `thread A`, and one second after, I query the same data in `thread B`, sometimes results in `thread B` are not updated with the latest data saved one second before in `thread A`.

I would like to know if is normal, or there is a way to mitigate it.

Comment: What's thread A and thread B?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I don't understand what you mean, thread A and B are different threads of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An open Realm on a given thread retains a versioned view of the underlying database. This can be updated automatically if the thread is associated with a Looper.

In case of a normal background thread, it does not have a looper, so it is updated if:

- all Realm instances on that thread are closed, then opened later
- a transaction is opened
- `refresh()` is called (note, if called on looper thread, this makes async queries be evaluated immediately)

You most likely end up with outdated data if you don't call `.close()` for each `getInstance()` call.

Comment: Okey, I will have everything into account, thanks you so much!